# SplFileObject iteration duplicates key 0

Tags: php, generator, splfileobject

All,

I cannot for the life of me, figure out why `\SplFileObject` is repeating the key in the following code. This sample uses Nowdoc as a file stream but this effect can be noted using any file.

PHP Code:

```
$str = <<<'EOD'
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
Line 4
Line 5
EOD;

$file = new \SplFileObject('data://text/plain;base64,' . base64_encode($str));
$iterator = call_user_func(function (\SplFileObject $file) {
  while (!$file->eof()) {
    yield [$file->key() => $file->fgets()];
  }
}, $file);

foreach ($iterator as $line) {
  echo key($line) . ': ' . current($line) . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Output:

```
0: Line 1
0: Line 2
1: Line 3
2: Line 4
3: Line 5
```

Comment: why not just do this: `$file = new \SplFileObject('data://text/plain;base64,' . base64_encode($str)); foreach($file as $line){
 echo $file->key() . ". " . $line;
}` https://ideone.com/60kEfB

Comment: @smith I'm specifically using the Generator class because, while this sample is small, the file I'm parsing is 500K+ lines long and I'm trying to reduce the memory usage.

Comment: @paul-crovella I don't understand why the key is separate from the line. It's not an iteration, it's a method from the SplFileObject class that tells you what line it's reading. If the line advances, so does the key.

Comment: I too find it weird that key didn't update when it's matching `fgets()` was called; anyway Paul pointed it right it's because the value gets binded and later fgets doesn't affect that binded value, i guess some pass by ref. should solve this

Comment: Or... use `yield array_flip([$file->fgets() => $file->key()]);` ;)